# What are the differences between Frames and Image Schemata?

Tags: psycholinguistics, cognitive-linguistics

I know there are several schema based theories in cognitive sciences, including psychology and linguistics. I am also aware that they mostly share a lot in common, as, for instance, Rumelhart (1981) explains.

However, I am looking for specific differences between the notion of Frames (as proposed by i.e. Fillmore, 1976; Langacker, etc) and the notion of Image Schema (as proposed by Johnson, 1987, Lakoff, etc).

References

- Fillmore, C. J. (1976). Frame Semantics and The Nature of Language. Annals of The New York Academy of Sciences, 280(1), 20-32. doi:10.1111/j.1749-6632.1976.tb25467.x
- Johnson, M. (1987) The Body in the Mind. Chicago: The University of Chicago Press.
- Rumelhart, D. E. (1981). Schemata: The Building Blocks of Cognition. In J. T. Guthrie (Ed.), Comprehension and teaching: Research reviews (pp. 3-26). Newark: International Reading Association.